# How to perform the click of Actionbar item in Sherlock Fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I want to perform a click on actionbar item in my Sherlock Fragment.
My item is showing on fragment class on action bar, but when I click on the item , the Toast message is not shown.

Here is my Sherlock Fragment code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.profile_menu_items, menu);
         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
         
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.Online:
            // do s.th.
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "online", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
         default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
     


@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        
    }}
```

Here is the menu file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    
 <item android:id="@+id/Online"
       android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Online"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Use an Interface and a method called from your parent activity

Answer (score 1):

You can use interface for this, create one interface and in your MainActivity implements this interface, like in my case it is -

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SwitherInterface{
// rest of the code with implementation of changeToDrawer()
}
```

Define your interface -

```
public interface SwitherInterface {
    public void changeToDrawer();
}
```

Inside your fragment declare interface and initialize this in onAttach method -

```
SwitherInterface switcher;

@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity a) {
        super.onAttach(a);
        switcher = (SwitherInterface) a;
    }
```

And you can then use the declared methods directly by -

```
switcher.changeToDrawer();
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

ActionBar code is handled in the Activity (not a Fragment) - so you must perform the business logic here.

This is how the AB is designed to work, and is how the framework callbacks are currently handled.